# Can this powershell script be made as a one-liner?

Tags: powershell, scripting, office365, exchange-server

As the title goes, can this piece of "script" be made into a one-liner? Preferably without semicolons.

Why? Just for the fun and educational part of it **solely**.

```
$mbx=get-mailbox "a mailbox"
$calendar=$($mbx.PrimarySmtpAddress.toString()) + ":\" + (Get-MailboxFolderStatistics $mbx.PrimarySmtpAddress.toString() | Where-Object { $_.Foldertype -eq 'Calendar' } | Select-Object -First 1).Name
$var=Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $calendar -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | select-object @{Label="Identity";expression={$mbx.Alias}},FolderName,User,AccessRights
$var.Foreach({ if ($_.User.DisplayName -eq 'Test') { $_.User.DisplayName }})
```

The closest I've reached is 3 lines:

```
$mbx=get-mailbox "a mailbox"
$Perm=Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $($mbx.PrimarySmtpAddress.toString() + ":\" + (Get-MailboxFolderStatistics $mbx.PrimarySmtpAddress.toString() | Where-Object { $_.Foldertype -eq 'Calendar' } | Select-Object -First 1).Name) | Select-Object @{Label="Identity";expression={$mbx.Alias}},FolderName,User,AccessRights
$Perm.Foreach({ if ($_.User.DisplayName -eq 'Test') { $_.User.DisplayName }})
```

Edit:

I came a few steps closer but this requires input of mailbox two times.

```
@(Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $($(Get-Mailbox "a mailbox" | select-Object -ExpandProperty PrimarySmtpAddress).toString() + ":\" + (Get-MailboxFolderStatistics $(Get-Mailbox "a mailbox" | select-Object -ExpandProperty PrimarySmtpAddress).toString() | Where-Object { $_.Foldertype -eq 'Calendar' } | Select-Object -First 1).Name)).Foreach({ if ($_.User.DisplayName -eq 'Test') { $_.User.DisplayName }})
```

Comment: Anything can be a one-liner with enough semi-colons...

Comment: I get the whole educational aspect, but please don’t get hung up on one-liners.  Always, always opt for code readability and maintainability over ‘cleverness’.

Comment: @boxdog I never mentioned one-liners as being correct, I did however mention it was for the fun and educational part of it. ;)

Comment: If this is a thing that you want to do, go learn Perl instead...http://www.foo.be/docs/tpj/issues/vol3_2/tpj0302-0012.html

Comment: Whitespace is a good one for writing code that no one can maintain too https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(programming_language)

Comment: That is why I posted it as a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may work (PSv4+; a single statement that also works as a one-liner):

```
(Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity (
  ($mbx=Get-Mailbox 'a mailbox').PrimarySmtpAddress.ToString() + ":\" +                      #" 
   (Get-MailboxFolderStatistics $mbx.PrimarySmtpAddress.ToString()).
     Where({$_.FolderType -eq 'Calendar'}, 'First').Name
 ) | Select-Object @{Label='Identity';expression={$mbx.Alias}},FolderName,User,AccessRights
).Where({ $_.User.DisplayName -eq 'Test' })
```

<sup>Note that [`Get-MailboxFolderStatistics`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/Get-MailboxFolderStatistics?view=exchange-ps), even though it expects a mailbox argument,  doesn't *directly* accept the `[Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.Management.Mailbox]` instance stored in `$mbx`, so `$mbx.PrimarySmtpAddress.ToString()` is needed; thanks, [NiklasJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487650/niklasj).</sup>

There can be elegance in concision, though crossing into obfuscation is easy, especially with overly long lines.

The above strives for the former, using a *single statement spread across multiple lines* with indentation clarifying the structure.

- Note that due to how the line breaks are placed, use of `` ` `` for line continuation is *not* necessary.
- Note how `$mbx` is assigned inside an expression early and reused later in the command.
- Note the use of PSv4+ collection operator `.Where(...)` with mode argument `First`, which is a more efficient alternative to `| Where-Object ... | Select-Object -First 1`
- The command's output is all those objects created with `Select-Object` whose `.User.DisplayName` value is string `Test`.

  - To achieve the original command's output, all you need to append is `.User.DisplayName`, but note that that will simply output any number of `Test` string instances (or case variations thereof), without further context.

Answer (score 0):

```
$mbx=get-mailbox "a mailbox"; $Perm=Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $($mbx.PrimarySmtpAddress.toString() + ":\" + (Get-MailboxFolderStatistics $mbx.PrimarySmtpAddress.toString() | Where-Object { $_.Foldertype -eq 'Calendar' } | Select-Object -First 1).Name) | Select-Object @{Label="Identity";expression={$mbx.Alias}},FolderName,User,AccessRights; $Perm.Foreach({ if ($_.User.DisplayName -eq 'Test') { $_.User.DisplayName }})
```

Comment: Semicolons is not really what I'm looking for. Any script can be semicoloned to a one-liner.

Comment: Because you have nested process blocks, you will have to use semi-colons at some point. This is just the simplest way of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the obvious answer is to create a function:

```
Function Start-OneLiner
{
    Param
    (
        [String]
        $Name
    )
    $mbx=Get-Mailbox $Name
    $calendar=$($mbx.PrimarySmtpAddress.toString()) + ":\" + (Get-MailboxFolderStatistics $mbx.PrimarySmtpAddress.toString() | Where-Object { $_.Foldertype -eq 'Calendar' } | Select-Object -First 1).Name
    $var=Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $calendar -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | select-object @{Label="Identity";expression={$mbx.Alias}},FolderName,User,AccessRights
    $var.Foreach({ if ($_.User.DisplayName -eq 'Test') { $_.User.DisplayName }})
}
```

A function can be [dot sourced](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2010/08/10/how-to-reuse-windows-powershell-functions-in-scripts/) from a `.ps1` file or can be [automatically loaded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878284(v=vs.85).aspx) (Powershell 3.0 and newer) by [creating a module](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878340%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Your one liner will be:

```
Start-OneLiner -name a mailbox
```

Answer (score 0):

I've reached another solution that works, one that is a mock-up of [mklement0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49517250/487650) but selectively defines what sub-properties are collected and later on parsed for specific values into the query.

One-liner:

```
(Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity ( ( $mbx=(Get-Mailbox 'a mailbox' | select-object Identity,PrimarySmtpAddress,Alias) ).PrimarySmtpAddress.ToString() + ":\" + ((Get-MailboxFolderStatistics $mbx.Identity).Where{$_.FolderType -eq 'Calendar'}|Select-Object -First 1).Name )| Select-Object @{Label='Identity';expression={$mbx.Alias}},FolderName,User,AccessRights).Where({ $_.User.DisplayName -eq 'Test' })
```

Readable:

```
(
    Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity ( 
        ( $mbx=(Get-Mailbox 'a mailbox' | select-object Identity,PrimarySmtpAddress,Alias) ).PrimarySmtpAddress.ToString() + ":\" +                 #"
        (
            (Get-MailboxFolderStatistics $mbx.Identity).Where{
                $_.FolderType -eq 'Calendar'
            }
            |Select-Object -First 1
        ).Name
    )
    | Select-Object @{Label='Identity';expression={$mbx.Alias}},FolderName,User,AccessRights
).Where(
    { $_.User.DisplayName -eq 'Test' }
)
```